# How can I adjust the width of legend images in PGFPlots?

Tags: pgfplots, legend

I am using pgfplots to create charts. How can I adjust the width of images of legend entries? 
I have adjusted plot coordinates in legend image code in the line legend style, but this not worked truely. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem.